# Reactjs app building successfully when deploying with Heroku but still getting Application Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, package.json

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my React application successfully running with Heroku. 
It is building successfully but im getting the `Application Error` notice when visiting the URL.

I was wondering can you help. I've searched for the answer to my problem but no luck.

Here's some information on the application
I've built an app with the `create-react-app` command.

I'm running Node v6.10.2 on my computer.

To deploy the app I entered the following command from my project folder:

```
npm run build
```

(This created a "build" folder.)

Then I entered the following command:

```
cd build
```

I created a package.json file (for the build folder) as there was none.

```
{
  "name": "alien_relatives",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,

"dependencies": {
"classnames": "^2.2.5",  
"react": "^15.6.1",
"react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },

"devDependencies": {  
"react-scripts": "1.0.10"
  },
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build", 
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

In the build folder I ran the following commands.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "all files"

heroku create alienrelatives
git push heroku master
```

The following was output to the console:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 6.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.10
remote:
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Skipping cache restore (new-signature)
remote:
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        alien_relatives@0.1.0 /tmp/build_e0b8b2ea1ffb5d7006e8f910f2683e47

remote:        +-- classnames@2.2.5
remote:        +-- react@15.6.1
remote:        ¦ +-- create-react-class@15.6.0
remote:        ¦ +-- fbjs@0.8.14
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- core-js@1.2.7
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- isomorphic-fetch@2.2.1
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- node-fetch@1.7.1
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- encoding@0.1.12
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- iconv-lite@0.4.18
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- is-stream@1.1.0
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- whatwg-fetch@2.0.3
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- promise@7.3.1
remote:        ¦ ¦ ¦ +-- asap@2.0.6
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- setimmediate@1.0.5
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- ua-parser-js@0.7.14
remote:        ¦ +-- loose-envify@1.3.1
remote:        ¦ ¦ +-- js-tokens@3.0.2
remote:        ¦ +-- object-assign@4.1.1
remote:        ¦ +-- prop-types@15.5.10
remote:        +-- react-dom@15.6.1
remote:
remote:
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote:
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 16.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://alienrelatives.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/alienrelatives.git
   caf3245..11c44c2  master -> master
```

But when i visit the URL it says

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. 
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

When I open the developer tools in the browser I see this in the console:

```
(unknown) Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.herokucdn.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

at <anonymous>:1:15

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable) /favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Heroku support and I got it sorted so here's the answer:

To deploy an app (on Heroku) which was created with the `create-react-app` command, you need to be using a custom buildpack, not the standard Node.js one.

For more details see: https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#quick-start

So I needed to run the following commands (in my project folder) in order to set the new buildpack and then also push my project to heroku once again:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git

git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

After I toke about a day searching about this, so I finally found this [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack#quick-start) so you have to do this in your terminal:-

1. Go to your application file and run this command if you already have exist application:
   `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git`.
2. then commit what you did like : `git commit -am "create-react-buildpack`.
3. Then Push to your Heroku repo `git push heroku master`.
4. after that you need to restart your dynos in heroku so run this command in your terminal `heroku restart` then `heroku open`

Comment: thanks for your answer but I also found a solution as you can see above. I appreciate your help though :)

Answer (score -1):

Clear and concise [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA4Fl1dZgjc) explanation, works perfectly for your problem using Heroku's Builpack feature under Settings.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tA4Fl1dZgjc
```